Emulator is not working getting attached error
Getting attached error while running emulator
Please help !
Encountering emulator attachment error on Windows 11. Struggling to locate advanced settings. Seeking assistance for resolution.

I tried to run the emulator, ensured all the SDK platform and SDK tools are present

The extended controls is accessed using the "..." button at the bottom of the panel to the right of the emulator screen.
